# Download pictures from OneDrive to memory stick

Tags: 8.1

How do I download pictures from OneDrive to a memory stick?

I have edited them in Fotor and it was then saved in OneDrive.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do this with a PC. You can download the pictures by going to [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/), then copy them over via Windows Explorer. Alternatively you could Bluetooth the pictures to your PC from your phone or copy them from your phone to your PC with Explorer, then copy them to the memory stick.